# How can I remove 1.4MHz and 150kHz switching noise?

Tags: noise, buck

(Please excuse my English)

I have two types of DC-DC step-down(buck) converter modules, and the switching frequencies of the converter modules are 1.4MHz and 150kHz each.
The two converter modules supply 3.3V power to two sensitive sensor boards. I should remove the switching noises of the converter modules.

However I cannot modify the circuits of the converter modules. The converter module circuits are fixed on PCB. So I want to append some circuits to V-out(3.3V) of the converter modules.

What are the simplest circuits for my purpose?

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE! Probably by fixing your layout and circuit first and filters secondary. Please show schematic and layout. Your English is fine by the way.

Comment: @winny Please let me know what part of my question is difficult to understand. My question is very simple, actually. I want circuits for removing switching noise of buck converter's V-out.

Comment: We need more data. e.g. if you 'sensor module' does not require too much current you could replace the converter with an LDO.

Comment: @Oldfart Though the sensor modules do not require much current, I cannot change the converters. My situation is more complicated than expressed here.

Comment: @pdh0710 - Welcome to the site :-) In the comment above, you said: "*My situation is more complicated than expressed here.*" You need to give us **all** the relevant constraints. Otherwise you risk wasting our time (and yours) writing answers, which end up being unsuitable due to missing information. You also risk getting downvotes or even the question being closed, if readers believe you are withholding relevant information. Please read the [tour] and [help] for more information about how to use the site. Can you provide some photos of the existing buck converters, and list *all* constraints?

Comment: It's not difficult to understand. You still need to show schematic and layout if you want any specific help. What you have going for you is that 1.4 MHz is faily low so differential filters do stand a chance here.

Comment: @SamGibson Thank you for your comment. I understand what you meant, but I don't think Oldfart's comment is waste of time. I only explained why I cannot accept Oldfart's solution current time. I think there will be times when Oldfart's solution will be useful in the future. Also, someone in the situation different from me will read the commnet and find it useful, in the future. The questions and comments posted on StackExchange are in public domain. Many many people in different situations read them and get useful information from them.

Comment: @winny O.K. I will describe my situation more specifically in the future.

Comment: The best design is the one with the best specifications.  for analog... V,I,Z (f) with tolerances

Comment: Without quantitative details, the only answer that can be given is to "add a filter." Maybe an RC filter or maybe an LC filter. If you can tell us how much ripple you have on the 3.3V rail and how much ripple you can tolerate, we can give you some ideas about what kind of filter may be required. Also, I am assuming that your sensitive sensors consume a steady current. But if that is not the case, if there is ripple in the load current, that needs to be specified also. An extreme filter solution would be to boost up to 4V or 4.5V and then use an LDO down to 3.3V.

Comment: @mkeith As Bimpelrekkie pointed out in the answer below, I chose wrong expression "remove switching noise" in this question, instead correct expression `reduce switching noise`. I did not understand the problem specifically when I posted this question. What I know was the switching noise of buck converter is well-known problem. So I expected a simple and general solution. Now I can understand that I should know more specifically for the problem. And I will. Thank you.

Comment: Well I tried to show examples, but this still depends on source and load impedance

Comment: @SunnyskyguyEE75 I will find out those parameters through experiments. Thank you again.

Comment: It's a function of impedance ratios

Comment: @SunnyskyguyEE75 O.K. I will remember it.

Answer (score 4):

**1) All** DCDC converters will produce some ripple (switching noise) at their output. It is **unavoidable** and inherent to the way switched DCDC converters work.

**2)** Before you continue, read and understand 1) and if you understand 1) correctly then your conclusion should be that you will not be able to **completely** remove the switching noise. So you will have to determine how much switching noise is acceptable. So how much lower does the ripple need to be, for example 10 dB lower at 150 kHz or 20 dB or 40 dB? Note that if you say: "But of course I want 40 dB!" then I'll say, OK, that will cost more (more complex filter, more expensive components) etc. but also: Would you like 80 dB suppression? And if you then say "yes please" we will go on and on and your design will be infinitely expensive and have way too much suppression. So figure out what is **really** needed. Yes, that might not be easy.

**3)** Once you know how much switching noise is acceptable you could choose to filter the output voltage of the DCDC converter. A filter like this could do the job:

[image]

Another option would be to use an LDO (linear regulator) for supply voltage regulation. An example: a DCDC converter is used to convert 12 V to 5 V, that 5 V with the switching noise is then regulated by an LDO down to a far less noisy 3.3 V.

Comment: O.K. I understand 1) and 2). I'll try the L-C filters as you recommended in 3). (As mentioned in the comments above, I cannot change the converters)

Comment: @Bimp  Unless you know the X(f)/R ratio. this will amplify the noise

Comment: if 3 people approve of this answer , they could be making a big mistake.

Comment: Do an error-budget, for the signal-noise-ratio you need. If you cannot generate a useful error-budget, then ask an experienced person.

Comment: @SunnyskyguyEE75 I think the switching noise may be amplified or attenuated depending on the values of L and C. Before I posted the above question, I tried a simple L-C filter without any calculation. Fortunately, it slightly attenuated the 1.4MHz switching noise (10mV to 8~9mV). Of course, this result was not satisfactory. So I posted the above question.

Comment: If you want to design it correctly rather than trial and error, give specs: loss tolerances for passband and stop band then it can be done with load

Comment: This is a bad example of L / C filter https://i.stack.imgur.com/tyvk0.png and why R / L+C is better for series / shunt

Comment: @SunnyskyguyEE75 Though well-made simulations significantly reduce the range of trial, the trial and error method can not be totally eliminated. Because... 1) The above L-C filter is actually a part of more complex filter, due to buck converter's the output impedance and the load impedance. 2) Available inductors and capacitors have no exact values and no ideal characteristics.

Comment: Only if the results differ from simulation by the error budget using exact part characteristics including ESR, DCR, SRF.  The point is if you have no specs and no error budget, then you never have a controlled process. Cpk which is the indicator of a good design and process tolerance. This eliminates guesswork.

Answer (score 2):

Another way is to specify the load current Min and max then the low frequency ripple peak min,max Rs=ΔV/ΔI  and choose the series drop Rs  ( Load regulation )

- then select LC values for the notch filter. where f error contributes to variation in attenuation with Q and external impedances matter!!

[image]
[image]
If you search my answers for RLC impedance nomograph you can chose these values on a graph.
[image]

Comment: Hmm... This is not simple circuit I expected. However, I think this circuit will work better for the sensitive sensor boards. I will try this circuit. Thank you.

Comment: Oh, thank you very much for your various filter circuits. They are very helpful to me.